# bass analysis exercise 6.9

Tags: measure-theory

The following problem comes from bass analysis for graduate student

Let $(X, A, \mu)$ be a finite measure space and suppose
$f$ is a non-negative, measurable function that is finite at each
point of $X$, but not necessarily integrable. Prove that there exists
a continuous increasing function $g : [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ such that
$\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x) = \infty$ and $g \circ f$ is integrable.

Please help me, I have no ideal how to tackle this.

Comment: Look at $a_n=m(\{n\leq f<n+1\})$. You have that $\sum_n a_n=m(X)<\infty$. and $\sum_{n}(n+1)a_n$ might be divergent. Show first that you can have $b_n$ increasing to infinity such that $\sum_n b_n a_n<\infty$. Then define $g(n)=b_n$ and fill in the definition of $g$ by linear interpolation, for example.

Comment: To construct the $b_n$ check if you have seen a proof that there is no slowest convergent series. Maybe even in that book it was done. One way is to take $b_n=(\sum_{k>n} a_n)^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there might be a more elegant way to do. But here is my proof. Maybe it is too late for your homework.

> **Lemma** Let $\left ( X, \mathcal{A}, \mu \right )$ be a finite measure space. Then $f$ is integrable if and only if 
>   $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu \left ( \left \{ f \geq n\right \} \right ) < \infty$$

This lemma can be proved by invoking Abel summation. It is available online.

Now notice that $\mu \left ( \left \{ f \geq \alpha\right \} \right )$ decreases with $\alpha$ and it dies eventually since $f$ is finite at each point.

This means we can pick $a_n $ increasing to $\infty$ and $$\mu \left ( \left \{ f \geq a_n\right \} \right ) < \frac{1}{2^n} \mu(X).$$

Also, we delete all the same $a_i$ so $i<j$ implies $a_i < a_j$. Now define $g$ to be the linear interpolation of the following sequence of points:

$$\left \{ \left ( 0, 0 \right ), \left ( a_1, 1 \right ), \left ( a_2, 2 \right ), \cdots \right \}.$$

$g$ is piecewisely linear, so it is continuous. Also, it goes to $\infty$ as $x$ goes to $\infty$. See that $$g\circ f \geq n \Leftrightarrow f\geq g^{-1}(n) = a_n.$$

Therefore,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu \left ( \left \{ g\circ f \geq n\right \} \right )  = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu \left ( \left \{ f \geq a_n\right \} \right ) < \infty.$$

By the Lemma, $g\circ f$ is integrable.

Comment: Thank you. It's not actually for my homework.